# dofile works but call a stack traceback

Tags: lua, lua-5.3

main.lua

```
dofile("example.lua")
```

example.lua

```
print "Hello World"
```

results in:

```
Hello World
lua: main.lua:1: attempt to call a nil value
stack traceback:
    main.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

But I don't understand why?

Comment: How are you executing `main.lua`?

Comment: prompt> lua main.lua

Comment: Probably, you have something else in `example.lua` or `main.lua`: `(...)` or `{...}` or `"..."` on its second line?

Comment: Add `return print` at the end of `example.lua` to test @Egor's hypothesis.

Comment: [Cannot replicate](https://gfycat.com/PoorExcellentAnole), Lua 5.3.3. Please ensure you are providing us with accurate details.

Comment: Thanks @Egor, i thought the other lines in main.lua are unimportant because of the traceback